# Static inapp billing test error [ RPC:S-7:AEC-0 ]

Tags: android, testing, billing, apportable

I'm porting my iOS app to Android via Apportable and I'm stuck on billing. I'm trying to start from test static purchase ( product : android.test.purchased ), products request show that product exist, but when I'm trying to purchase it - error RPC:S-7:AEC-0 occurred. I'm install apk with command :

BUILD=release BUILD_TIMESTAMP=numerictimestamp SIGNING_PUBKEY=longstringfromdevconsole ANDROID_KEYSTORE='path/release.keystore' ANDROID_KEY_NAME=mykey ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASS='mypass' apportable load

Is there any requirements to accounts that can make static purchase test? Previously I've upload apk with billing permission in console as work build. I'm new to android so lil confused with that signing stuff and alfa/beta channels. What I'm doing wrong?